# Need help applying this function to a Pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, anaconda

I am trying to look up the skus of products in my allinv_styles dataframe by looking up the parent asin for the sku and counting rows that meet certain conditions but I don't know what I'm doing and I would greatly appreciate your help.

**I am getting the error message: "ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar."**

I have two dataframes adgroups_df and allinv_styles.

adgroups_df has a column called "Ad Group" that contains the sku of a product.

A sku is specific to a product in style and size. Like black small. A parent asin can have many skus and styles. I'm trying to write a function to calculate the out of stock percentage of the style that the ad group represents.

My thought process is:

- find parent asin of ad group
- id ad group style
- look up that row's parent asin
- count how many rows of that style are in that parent asin
- count how many rows have stock < 0
- calculate oos %
- return oos %
- create new column by applying function to every Ad Group column

This is my spaghetti code:

```
def calc_style_OOS(adgroups):
    for sku in adgroups:
        # find parent asin of ad group sku
        parentasin = allinv_styles.loc[(allinv_styles['sku'] == sku)]['(Parent) ASIN'].item()

        # I tried to print here to debug...
        print(parentasin)

        # find style of sku
        style = allinv_styles.loc[(allinv_styles['sku'] == sku)]['style'].item()

        # how many variations does this style have?
        total_variations = len(allinv_styles.loc[(allinv_styles['(Parent) ASIN'] == parentasin) &
                  (allinv_styles['style'] == style)])

        # how many of these rows have 0 stock?
        oos_variations = len(allinv_styles.loc[(allinv_styles['(Parent) ASIN'] == parentasin) &
                  (allinv_styles['style'] == style) &
                  (allinv_styles['afn-fulfillable-quantity'] < 0)])

        # caclulate oos %

        if total_variations == 0:
        return 0
        else: 
            oos = oos_variations/total_variations
            return oos

adgroups_df['OOS %'] = adgroups_df['Ad Group'].apply(calc_style_OOS)
```

In depth error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-7ba9d94d5581> in <module>()
----> 1 adgroups_df['OOS %'] = adgroups_df['Ad Group'].apply(calc_style_OOS)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   2549             else:
   2550                 values = self.asobject
-> 2551                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   2552 
   2553         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-36-ac54497ca2ef> in calc_style_OOS(adgroups)
     14     for sku in adgroups:
     15         # find parent asin of ad group sku
---> 16         parentasin = allinv_styles.loc[(allinv_styles['sku'] == sku)]['(Parent) ASIN'].item()
     17         # I tried to print here to debug...
     18         print(parentasin)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py in item(self)
    717         """
    718         try:
--> 719             return self.values.item()
    720         except IndexError:
    721             # copy numpy's message here because Py26 raises an IndexError

ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def calc_style_OOS(adgroup):

# edge case ad group not in df

if len(allinv_styles[allinv_styles['sku'].isin([adgroup])]) == 0: 
    return 'No data'

else:

    # find parent asin of ad group sku
    parentasin = allinv_styles[['sku','(Parent) ASIN']].drop_duplicates().set_index('sku')['(Parent) ASIN'][adgroup]
    #print(parentasin)

    # find style of sku
    style = allinv_styles[['sku', 'style']].drop_duplicates().set_index('sku')['style'][adgroup]

    # how many variations does this style have?
    total_variations = len(allinv_styles.loc[(allinv_styles['(Parent) ASIN'] == parentasin) &
                                             (allinv_styles['style'] == style)])

    # how many of these rows have 0 stock?
    oos_variations = len(allinv_styles.loc[(allinv_styles['(Parent) ASIN'] == parentasin) &
                                           (allinv_styles['style'] == style) &
                                           (allinv_styles['afn-fulfillable-quantity'] < 1)])

    # caclulate oos %
    if total_variations == 0:
        return 0
    else: 
        return oos_variations/total_variations
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand the problem correctly, change this:

```
def calc_style_OOS(adgroups):
    for sku in adgroups:
```

to this:

```
def calc_style_OOS(sku):
```

`Series.apply` is applying the function element-wise, you don't need the loop in `calc_style_OOS`.

You need to pass `allinv_styles` as an argument to `apply` if you want to use it in `calc_style_OOS`:

```
adgroups_df['OOS %'] = adgroups_df['Ad Group'].apply(calc_style_OOS, args=（allinv_styles,))
```

However, i think you should create 4 temporary columns for `(Parent) ASIN`, `style`, `total_variations` and `oos_variations` instead of calculating each one in a custom `apply` function.

**Example (not tested)**

```
# Map (Parent) ASIN
adgroups_df['(Parent) ASIN'] = adgroups_df.sku.map(dict(zip(allinv_styles.sku, allinv_styles['(Parent) ASIN'])))

# Map style
adgroups_df['style'] = adgroups_df.sku.map(dict(zip(allinv_styles.sku, allinv_styles.style)))

# Get variation counts
group_cols = ['(Parent) ASIN', 'style']
total_variations = allinv_styles[group_cols].groupby(group_cols).size()
oos_variations = allinv_styles['afn-fulfillable-quantity'] < 0)][group_cols].groupby(group_cols).size()

# Calculate %, map back to adgroups_df
oos_percents = oos_variations / total_variations
oos_percents = oos_percents.where(oos_percents != np.inf, 0)
adgroups_df = adgroups_df.join(oos_percents, on=group_cols)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm getting a new key error after implementing your recommended changes: KeyError: 'Parent ASIN' at `---> 23     total_variations = allinv_styles[['(Parent) ASIN', 'style', 'sku']].groupby(['Parent ASIN', 'style']).transform('count')`

Comment: Thank you so much for your continuous help. I am getting: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map' at `----> 2 adgroups_df['(Parent) ASIN'] = adgroups_df.map(dict(zip(allinv_styles.sku, allinv_styles['(Parent) ASIN'])))
`

Comment: sorry, missed out `sku`: `adgroups_df.sku.map(dict(zip(allinv_styles.sku, allinv_styles['(Parent) ASIN'])))`